# How to texture a resmesh with such accuracy?

Tags: materials, shaders, remesh

So I've tried achieving a result similar to mikecampau with his series BlockHeadPunk
https://www.instagram.com/p/CScQW89nDtC/
But when I try to retexture my head (previously modified with remesh) with a data transfer, I can't get anything that precise at all! Any clue on how to achieve a similar look?
Thank you!! :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.